# Implement of original strlcpy function on Libc

Tags: c, libc, bsd

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t  ft_strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t dstsize)
{
    unsigned int    i;
    unsigned int    dst_len;

    i = 0;
    dst_len = strlen(dst);
    if (dstsize > 0)
    {
        while (src[i] != '\0' && i < dstsize - 1)
        {
            dst[i] = src[i];
            i++;
        }
        dst[i] = '\0';
    }
    return (strlen(src));
}

int    main(void)
{
    char dst[100] = "HelloWorld!";
    char dst2[100] = "HelloWorld!";

    const char src[11] = "teststring";
    int dstsize = -1;
    printf("mine : %zu\n", ft_strlcpy(dst, src, dstsize));
    printf("%s\n", dst);
    printf("string.h : %zu\n", strlcpy(dst2, src, dstsize));
    printf("%s\n", dst2);


    return (0);
}
```

This code is my code of implementing strlcpy on my own.

but I have one doubt question.

when dstsize is negative number, my fucntion don't print any error message.

but original strlcpy print Tracetrap error(maybe SIGILL in linux. I'm using OS X)

[image: error]

I have searched most of bsd original c library github, but all of them work same as my code. I want to know the difference. how original strlcpy print error when dstsize is negative number?

This question's point is "how to print trace trap error when dstsize is negative number like original function?(I know it will be converted to size_t max number.)"

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type, so it can't be negative. But anyway, what error message do you expect?

Comment: `dstsize` can't be a negative number, since it is of type `size_t` which is an unsigned type. When the argument is -1, it will be converted to an unsigned value which is the maximum value of size_t.

Comment: yup. I know about that. when size_t convert -1 to maximum value of size_t, how to know it and original function print trace trap error? I just want to make my code work like original function.

Comment: Side note: `const char src[10] = "teststring";` is probably not what you want. Here `src` is not null terminated because there is no room for the null terminator. You probably want `char src[11] = ...` or better `char src[] = ...`. With latter the compiler takes care of reserving the right quantity of memory for your string.

Comment: @Jabberwocky sorry about that. but this question's point is not about that..

Comment: @jyoung  I know, that's why it is a "Side note". It a bonus, take it or leave it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky `src` not being null-terminated is the problem. First thing `strlcpy` does is `strlen(src)` see https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/main/osfmk/arm/strlcpy.c . I think this is a case of UB behaving differently in two cases, and has nothing to do with `dstsize`.

Comment: If you replace the declaration of `src` with `const char *src = "teststring";` then I guess there's no trap.

Comment: @PaulHankin if src makes error, first output "mine : 10" shouldn't be printed.

Comment: @jyoung `src` is not null terminated, therefore all your tests are pointless.

Comment: @jyoung the original `strlcpy` function doesn't deal with negative  size either as `size_t` is unsigned.

Comment: @Jabberwocky please see my question again. I edited the code. but same error happens

Comment: @jyoung but what output do you expect?

Comment: @Jabberwocky need trace trap sig like original function.

Comment: @jyoung the original strlcpy function is not documented to do that. If `src` is null terminated (like in the edited version of your code), your code runs fine without any error message. Check this: https://www.godbolt.org/z/fjPbE15zj. BTW: don't declare your strings like this: `const char src[11] = "teststring";`, it's bad practice and it's error prone. Do this: `const char src[] = "teststring";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to compute the length of the string in `dst` for `strlcpy`: `dst_len = strlen(dst);` is useless and counterproductive.

Here is a modified version:

```
size_t  ft_strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t dstsize)
{
    size_t    i;

    i = 0;
    while (i + 1 < dstsize && src[i] != '\0') {
        dst[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    if (i < dstsize) {
        dst[i] = '\0';
    }
    while (src[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Regarding your question:

> how to print trace trap error when `dstsize` is a negative number?(I know it will be converted to `size_t` max number.)

If the destination size passed by the caller is a negative number, ie: the result of some computation that produces or would produce a negative number using signed arithmetics, it is converted to `size_t` modulo `SIZE_MAX + 1`, hence the value is huge.

You can detect this by comparison:

```
 if (dstsize > SIZE_MAX >> 1) {
     fprintf(stderr, "ft_strlcpy: huge dstsize indicates a negative value was passed: %zd\n", dstsize);
     abort();
 }
```

Comment: That's not the point.. the point is "how to print trace trap error when dstsize is negative number?(I know it will be converted to size_t max number.)"

Comment: @jyoung as mentioned several times, `dstsize` is an unsigned value. It cannot be negative.

Comment: Yup. after -1 convert to size_t max number, it's same as put size_t max number at dstsize. when it occurs, how to print trace trap error like original function?

Comment: thanks for additional answer. so is that the only way to print error with abort function? I think "SIGABORT" is not the same sig "SIGTRAP"(OS X) or "SIGILL"(LINUX)

Comment: @jyoung: you can send a signal using the `raise` system call: `#include <signal.h>  [...] raise(SIGTRAP);`